# error in canActivate guard method

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Below is my implementation of CanActivate guard clause in TypeScript , when I compile this  code , it shows below error

> A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value

```
   canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot):boolean {

     this.appService.isValidUser().subscribe({
        next: (data) => data.authenticated, // this return true or false
        error: (err) => false
    });
}
```

What is the reason for this error ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`canActivate` should return an `Observable` not a `Subscription`. If you call `.subscribe()`, you'll get a `Subscription`, therefore we use `.map()`.

To handle the error case use `.catch()`

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot):Observable<boolean> {

  return this.appService.isValidUser()
  .map(data => data.authenticated)
  .catch(_ => Observable.of([false]));
}
```

Don't forget to import all operators

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

Comment: Shouldn't  return type should be Observable<boolean> ?

Comment: @Martin you mean `Observable<boolean>.of(...)`? I don't use TS myself (only in Plunker) and there I don't get errors about missing generic types.

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer , I think  he is  telling about return type of canActivate method